# &dagger and &Dagger in Excel on Mac

Tags: html, excel, csv, html-entities, macos

I have an html file that gets written to be downloaded with Excel. In that file I have the † and &Dagger entities being used. On Windows, Excel shows the dagger correctly but on Mac it does not.

Any fix to this?